# How often should alkaline batteries be checked when they are in a device?

Tags: electrical

I have the problem of leaving alkaline batteries in various devices, and have lost some I could not clean with vinegar.  If I don't use the device, I take the batteries out.  But a lot of devices are used frequently.  To avoid leakages, how often should the batteries be checked, and how should they be checked?

Answer (score 13):

### You don't need to check devices used frequently

Because you will soon notice that the device has gone inoperative, and will simply change the batteries at that point.  What gets 'ya is devices you rarely use.

One option is to use *rechargeable* batteries in those rarely used devices, which is to say NiCd or NiMH batteries. They will still discharge, however they won't be damaged by doing so.  In fact,  NiCds and NiMH's *normally* self-discharge over time, so if left in a drawer for a year, they will be fully discharged within 90 days and spend 275 days in a fully discharged state, without taking any damage.

Obviously after 90 days the device will not be usable and you'll have to take the batteries out and charge them; but you use them rarely anyway.

If you *need* to have your rarely-used devices "ready and good to go", then my advice is to use primary cells (non-rechargeable), and change batteries annually.  Don't throw out the old batteries; just demote them to frequently used appliances.

Comment: Low-self discharge (LSD) NiMH rechargeable batteries can be a good choice for infrequently used devices. They keep power longer than regular NiMH batteries and also won't leak.

Answer (score 12):

Alkaline batteries should only leak once they go flat or are physically damaged. [Basic info here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkaline_battery#Leaks). [More info here](http://data.energizer.com/pdfs/alkaline_appman.pdf). So the trick is to remove batteries as soon as they are flat or almost flat (below ~0.9V per cell). If you can't tell when they're flat (i.e. no multi-meter available) it is best to follow the advice of some manufacturers who recommend removing batteries whenever not in use.

Another alternative would be to use the Lithium-Iron Disulfide type as these don't leak or dry out like alkaline cells, and they have much better shelf life and temperature tolerance and roughly double the energy density, don't produce hydrogen in sealed enclosures (like dive lights) when abused (so consequently your dive lights won't explode). They are made by Energizer under the "Energizer Lithium" label typically, or by GP in China (equally good in my opinion). They have higher initial voltage (~1.8V) than alkalines typically.

A company I used to work for shipped around 300000 of these per annum with almost no problems, as compared to alkalines which caused countless headaches for support staff.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stack exchange. I'd like to read more about how alkaline batteries only leak when flat. Can you suggest some reading material?

Comment: For starters, [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkaline_battery#Leaks). But the data I found is buried in a (very useful) Energizer application note [link] (http://data.energizer.com/pdfs/alkaline_appman.pdf), although, I can't find the document which mentions 0.9V as cutoff (it may have been in an email from Energizer or Duracell), however, 0.9V is considered completely flat

Comment: Good stuff - I have added the links to your answer. You might consider adding the  end of your comment to your answer as well.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. First answer, and it's a good one; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Comment: In my experience, this simply isn't true. Yesterday I spent all day cleaning two severely damaged D cell Maglites. The pitting of the housings was very nearly full thickness on both flashlights. Both turned on, shining bright, immediately before I opened them. I only opened them because other damaged devices had put me on a mission to remove alkaline batteries from pretty much everything. I still want to know how quickly alkaline batteries leak once they start. How often should I check them? Just turning something on isn't enough.

Comment: I have read both referenced articles and did not find where either stated that batteries only leak once they go flat. The Wikipedia article says pressure is created as they discharge, not once they are fully discharged.

Comment: Minutes ago I found two AA's that had leaked in storage. https://bit.ly/2RGISEe (Photo of box bottom and battery ends after cleaning) I tested with Fenix MC10 which uses a single AA and has three regulated brightness levels. If power is too low for next level it steps back down (or off). High only works with low resistance NiMh. A new alkaline can power Mid level. Low works down to 1 V. One of the bad batteries worked at low level only. The other worked even at mid level. I wouldn't have even known the battery was low, much less leaking, just by using the light.

Answer (score 6):

This is opinion, so I'd be interested if anyone has a more factual answer.

The problem is that battery manufacturers don't admit to their cells leaking.  They say they do not leak, and don't say things like "Won't leak for at least 5 years!".  So, when to check comes down to "how important is the device".  If it's very important, use a big name brand battery and simply replace the batteries once a year.  You can't tell that a battery is about to leak, so the only way to prevent it is to cycle them out.

Use the time change or New Years or some big even to remind yourself.  Regardless of how much is left in the batteries, replace them.  You can have a box for the partially depleted batteries and you can re-use them in high-drain devices if you don't want to waste any power.

Leaking is very unpredictable.  I've seen it happen in less than a year with generic batteries and I've also found a 15 year old CD player with good batteries that still powered on the display!

Comment: It also matters the type of application - temperature, impact, etc.I agree with Jphil1618 that this is more an opinion based question and almost impossible to answer objectively.

Comment: I've had more problems with leaking batteries the last few years than ever before even though I have fewer battery operated devices these days.  Not sure if they last longer before failing, so are more likely to leak, or if general quality is lower these days.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch -- I've seen Duracells leak in-package before their marked expiration date was up :/

Answer (score 0):

"I could not clean with vinegar" - yeah, I bet not; that's not casuistic enough nor even on my list: **spray can of contact cleaner, rubber eraser, or sandpaper... after cutting the excess crud off with a knife** or scraping it with a flathead - try not to damage the plating, but if you have to take it down to bare copper, so be it.

'I opened a device right away after it had quit working, and the battery had already leaked.' - that's going to happen once in a while. See above. The only thing I check batteries for is charge. [insert rant about how you're supposed to remove them, which none of us do]. If they're dead and leaked, it's time to change them and clean the contacts; simple as that.